# Is there a convention or standard of the highest bits in a sequence logo?

Tags: ngs, sequence-analysis

In bioinformatics, a [sequence logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo) is a graphical representation of the sequence conservation of nucleotides (in a strand of DNA/RNA) or amino acids (in protein sequences).

wiki says

> The total height of the letters depicts the information content of the
>   position, in bits.

and then gives this example

> A sequence logo showing the most conserved bases around the initiation
>   codon from all human mRNAs (Kozak consensus sequence). Note that the
>   initiation codon is not drawn to scale, otherwise the letters AUG
>   would each have a height of 2 bits.

[image: e]

it seems that there is a 0.1 bit letter.

is this in the context of 2bits? is 2bits the highest bits in this sequence logo? Is there a convention or standard of the highest bits in a sequence logo?

Comment: Sequence logos are usually just visual aids, why do you need the bits? I mean, if you want to get numbers representing the frequency of a residue at a given position, then logos are probably not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [the original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2172928) [1] describing the logos (emphasis mine):

> The importance of a particular position in a binding site is more clearly
>   and consistently given by the information required to describe the pattern
>   there [7, 8]. To choose one symbol or state from two equally likely possibilities
>   requires one "bit" of information. For example, to communicate the result of
>   a coin-ip to someone requires 1 bit of information because only one yes-no
>   question needs to be answered: "Is it heads?". **If a position in a binding
>   site always contains one base (e.g. G), then we need exactly two bits of
>   information since two yes-no questions need to be answered: "Is it A or G?"
>   (i.e. is it a purine?) and "Is it A or C?". (If the answers to both questions
>   are "no", it must be a T.)** Furthermore, if a position contains two bases (e.g.
>   sometimes A and sometimes G), only one question suffices since a two out of
>   four choice is equivalent to a one out of two choice. Therefore, only one bit
>   is needed to describe a position in a binding site that contains only purines,
>   but two bits are needed to describe a position that always contains adenine.

So yes, 2bits is the highest value you will see on the y-axis of a ***DNA*** sequence logo (proteins are a different story since there are more possibilities). In the one you show, the scale is from 0 to 0.2, but it's the same principle.

However, you should think of logos as a useful visual aid, and not a way of getting rigorous mathematical information about a sequence. So don't put too much weight on the bit values. If you need that sort of data, calculate it from the alignment directly.

---

[1] Schneider TD, Stephens RM., Sequence logos: a new way to display consensus sequences., *Nucleic Acids Res.* 1990 Oct 25;18(**20**):6097-100.